# Why doesn't this "res.redirect()" redirect?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect using nodejs and expressjs, but when I click on button nothing happens only url changes.
I'm using a form and within it has a button, this form has an action to "/failure"

```js
const express = require("express")
const bodyparser = require("body-parser")
const request = require("request")

const app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html")
})

app.post("/failure", function(req, res){
   res.redirect("/")
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000")
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Failure</title>
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
   <h1 class="display-4">Uh oh!</h1>
   <p class="lead">There was a problem signip you up Please try again or contact the developer!.</p>
   <form action="/failure" method="POST">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="submit" name="button">Try again</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I expecting redirect to page "signup.html"

Comment: But it is? You are starting on signup.html and then being redirected to signup.html?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
res.redirect(307, '/test');
```

});

This will preserve the send method, for more info you can check http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is correct. You are posting to the `'/failure'` route and within the handler of that route, it **is** redirecting to get `'/'` route handler which will return `signup.html` - which was your starting point.

You are posting to this:

```
app.post("/failure", function(req, res){
   res.redirect("/") // this is redirecting your route handler '/' which serves 'signup.html
})
```

Comment: The problem is doesn't redirect to "/".

Comment: But you have said "only url changes"? What is the starting point when you are first served the form?

Comment: Hi, res.redirect changes the content displayed on the screen but unfortunately the url doesnt chnage why is that?